# MFC - D3DCOLORVALUE undefined in base MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to create a new MFC Application.
I created the application using the setup wizard, left it on all the default values.

When testing if it even runs before adding anything it gave the compile error:

IntelliSense: identifier "D3DCOLORVALUE" is undefined

followed by a lot of:

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Why would this be happening in a stock standard application straight out of the wizard? And how would I get this working?

Comment: You probbaly forgot to include the appropriate Direct3d header file(s).

Comment: Where would I find the header files to include? And why would I have to manually add this in a stock standard application right out of the creation wizard?

Comment: `D3DCOLORVALUE` is Direct3D stuff. In which source file do you have this `D3DCOLORVALUE` symbol? How __exactly__ did you proceed to create the application with the wizard?

Comment: File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> MFC -> MFC Application -> Ok -> Finish -> F5 -> Yes. Even just doing that recreates this for me. D3DCOLORVALUE is defined in d2dbasetypes.h

Comment: Correction: The line that gives the error is in d2dbasetypes.h where D2D_COLOR_F is defined as type D3DCOLORVALUE. When I try go to the definition of D3DCOLORVALUE there it gives the error 'A definition for the symbol 'D3DCOLORVALUE' could not be located.'

Comment: I added #inclued "D3D9Types.h" found in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172520(v=vs.85).aspx and it seems to have fixed the problem. I dont know why this wasn't included in the base generated code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d2dbasetypes.h was giving the error when trying to define D2D_COLOR_F.
I googled the base type (D3DCOLORVALUE) and found that it's supposed to be in "D3D9Types.h"

I added `#include "D3D9Types.h"` to the top of the d2dbasetypes header file and it seems to have fixed the problem.

I don't know why this isn't included in the generated code by default...

Comment: That should really be `#include <D3D9Types.h>`. It isn't included by default, because the generated code should be minimal. If a developer decides to use Direct3D, they are expected to understand what headers and libraries they need to reference.